# avoid repeating code in xlsxwritter

Tags: xlsxwriter

I want to create time sheet with xlsxwritter, but I find some process and going to be tremendously long like this code below:

```
worksheet.set_column('B6:B6', 3)
worksheet.write('C9', "Day")
worksheet.write('C7', "Date")
worksheet.write('E7', "Start")
worksheet.write('F7', "End")

worksheet.write('C7', "SUN")
worksheet.write('C8', "MON")
worksheet.write('C9', "TUE")
worksheet.write('C10', "WED")
worksheet.write('C11', "THU")
worksheet.write('C12', "FRI")
worksheet.write('C13', "SAT")

worksheet.write('J7', "SUN")
worksheet.write('J8', "MON")
worksheet.write('J9', "TUE")
worksheet.write('J10', "WED")
worksheet.write('J11', "THU")
worksheet.write('J12', "FRI")
worksheet.write('J13', "SAT")

worksheet.write('N7', "SUN")
worksheet.write('N8', "MON")
worksheet.write('N9', "TUE")
worksheet.write('N10', "WED")
worksheet.write('N11', "THU")
worksheet.write('N12', "FRI")
worksheet.write('N13', "SAT")
```

To result like that in the pic:
[image]

Question : Is there any way to achieve such task without keep repeating the code >?

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit what you need?

You just need to adjust the SOME_MAX1 and SOME_MAX2 vars

```
days = ["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"]
rows = range(7,SOME_MAX1)
cols = range(3,SOME_MAX2,10) + range(9,SOME_MAX2,10)

for r in rows:
    for c in cols:
        worksheet.write( r, c, days[ r % 7 ] )
```

EDIT: For day, date, start, end: You can do something similar